# QGraphicsObject(0) instead of NULL in pointer

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a small game in Qt. I've got a board where every field has a pointer to unit. At the begin pointers are set to NULL. I'd like to check fields around my unit before move but

```
this->getRoom(-325,-325)->getUnit();
```

returns "QGraphicsObject(0)" not just "NULL" as I expected. I've changed my if instruction from:

```
if(this->getRoom(-325,-325)->getUnit()==0)
```

to:

```
if(this->getRoom(-325,-325)->getUnit()==QGraphicsObject(0))
```

but now I get: **invalid cast to abstract class type 'QGraphicsObject'**. Is there any other way to check these fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you didn't actually try to compare it against null? What's the harm in trying? :) It would have worked:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsItem *rect = 0;
    qDebug() << "is" << rect << "null?" << (rect == 0);
    return 0;
}
```

What's happening is that the `<<` operator [has been defined](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/graphicsview/qgraphicsitem.cpp#n11300) for that type:

```
if (!item) {
    debug << "QGraphicsItem(0)";
    return debug;
}
```

So, when you print it out, this function gets called and tries to print something useful rather than just a memory address. It sees that the pointer is null, so it prints out the type (`QGraphicsItem`) and `0`.